# Nested JSON and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I have a nest JSON file that looks like the below (first 2 of many objects):

```
{
"Abaddon the Despoiler": {
    "Abaddon the Despoiler": {
        "model_count": "1",
        "points_value": "220\u2022",
        "movement": "6\"",
        "weapon_skill": "2+",
        "ballistic_skill": "2+",
        "strength": "5",
        "toughness": "5",
        "wounds": "8",
        "attacks": "6",
        "leadership": "10",
        "save": "2+"
    }
},
"Chaos Lord": {
    "Chaos Lord": {
        "model_count": "1",
        "points_value": "80",
        "movement": "6\"",
        "weapon_skill": "2+",
        "ballistic_skill": "2+",
        "strength": "4",
        "toughness": "4",
        "wounds": "5",
        "attacks": "4",
        "leadership": "9",
        "save": "3+"
    }
},
```

I would like to convert this to a data frame that looks like the below:

| unit | model_count | points_value | movement | weapon_skill | ballistic_skill | strength | toughness | wounds | attacks | leadership | save |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abaddon the Despoiler | 1 | 220\u2022 | 6" | 2+ | 2+ | 5 | 5 | 8 | 6 | 10 | +2 |
| Chaos Lord | 1 | 80 | 6" | 2+ | 2+ | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 9 | +3 |

I think the solution is to use pandas json_normalize()

```
    #load json object
with open('./archive/chaos-space-marines.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

nycphil = pd.json_normalize(d)

nycphil.head(3)
```

however, when I do the below I get a data frame that is 1-row x 115 columns with column names like

```
Abaddon the Despoiler.Abaddon the Despoiler.model_count

Abaddon the Despoiler.Abaddon the Despoiler.points_value

Abaddon the Despoiler.Abaddon the Despoiler.movement    

Abaddon the Despoiler.Abaddon the Despoiler.weapon_skill
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a `list-comprehension` that reads your `dict`:

```
d = {'Abaddon the Despoiler': {'Abaddon the Despoiler': {'model_count': '1', 'points_value': '220•', 'movement': '6"', 'weapon_skill': '2+', 'ballistic_skill': '2+', 'strength': '5', 'toughness': '5', 'wounds': '8', 'attacks': '6', 'leadership': '10', 'save': '2+'}}, 
     'Chaos Lord':            {'Chaos Lord':            {'model_count': '1', 'points_value': '80','movement': '6"', 'weapon_skill': '2+', 'ballistic_skill': '2+', 'strength': '4', 'toughness': '4', 'wounds': '5', 'attacks': '4', 'leadership': '9', 'save': '3+'}}}

data = [{'unit': key, **values[key]} for key, values in d.items()]
nycphil = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: **When I do this I get an error message I have never seen before. I'm not so familiar with list comprehension**


import json

#load json object
with open('./archive/chaos-space-marines.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

data = [{'unit': key, **values[key]} for key, values in d.items()]
nycphil = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping

Comment: ive tried a few different methods such as looping through the inner dictionary is a similar manner to the above but I get similar errors

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: I'll try it with this exact subset and see what happens. Maybe there's a mistake in the list somehow

Comment: so it works with this subset I posted here, but not with the original. Ill need to investigate