# Nested JSON and Pandas v2

Tags: python, json, pandas

I asked a question yesterday about how to turn a JSON file into a dataframe, but I was asking the wrong question

[Nested JSON and Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676675/nested-json-and-pandas)

I have a JSON file that looks like the below

There are two levels of keys (some times repeating and other times not)

```
{
"Abaddon the Despoiler": {
    "Abaddon the Despoiler": {
        "model_count": "1",
        "points_value": "220\u2022",
        "movement": "6\"",
        "weapon_skill": "2+",
        "ballistic_skill": "2+",
        "strength": "5",
        "toughness": "5",
        "wounds": "8",
        "attacks": "6",
        "leadership": "10",
        "save": "2+"
    }
},
"Chaos Space Marines": {
    "Chaos Space Marine": {
        "model_count": "4-19",
        "points_value": "14",
        "movement": "6\"",
        "weapon_skill": "3+",
        "ballistic_skill": "3+",
        "strength": "4",
        "toughness": "4",
        "wounds": "1",
        "attacks": "1",
        "leadership": "7",
        "save": "3+"
    },
    "Aspiring Champion": {
        "model_count": "1",
        "points_value": "14",
        "movement": "6\"",
        "weapon_skill": "3+",
        "ballistic_skill": "3+",
        "strength": "4",
        "toughness": "4",
        "wounds": "1",
        "attacks": "2",
        "leadership": "8",
        "save": "3+"
    }
}
}
```

I would like to convert this to a data frame that looks like the below:

| unit | model | model_count | points_value | movement | weapon_skill | ballistic_skill | strength | toughness | wounds | attacks | leadership | save |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abaddon the Despoiler | Abaddon the Despoiler | 1 | 220\u2022 | 6" | 2+ | 2+ | 5 | 5 | 8 | 6 | 10 | +2 |
| Chaos Space Marines | Chaos Space Marines | 4-19 | 14 | 6" | 3+ | 3+ | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 7 | +3 |
| Chaos Space Marines | Aspiring Champion | 1 | 14 | 6" | 3+ | 3+ | 4 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 8 | +3 |

@azro provided this useful answer to my question yesterday, but I asked the wrong question. In the original question, I wanted to skip the second level of keys so it looked like the below

| unit | model_count | points_value | movement | weapon_skill | ballistic_skill | strength | toughness | wounds | attacks | leadership | save |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abaddon the Despoiler | 1 | 220\u2022 | 6" | 2+ | 2+ | 5 | 5 | 8 | 6 | 10 | +2 |
| Chaos Lord | 1 | 80 | 6" | 2+ | 2+ | 4 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 9 | +3 |

```
d = {'Abaddon the Despoiler': {'Abaddon the Despoiler': {'model_count': '1', 'points_value': '220•', 'movement': '6"', 'weapon_skill': '2+', 'ballistic_skill': '2+', 'strength': '5', 'toughness': '5', 'wounds': '8', 'attacks': '6', 'leadership': '10', 'save': '2+'}}, 
     'Chaos Lord':            {'Chaos Lord':            {'model_count': '1', 'points_value': '80','movement': '6"', 'weapon_skill': '2+', 'ballistic_skill': '2+', 'strength': '4', 'toughness': '4', 'wounds': '5', 'attacks': '4', 'leadership': '9', 'save': '3+'}}}

data = [{'unit': key, **values[key]} for key, values in d.items()]
nycphil = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with append dict to values of nested ditionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [{**{'unit': k, 'model': k1}, **v1} for k, v in d.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
                    unit                  model model_count points_value  \
0  Abaddon the Despoiler  Abaddon the Despoiler           1         220•   
1    Chaos Space Marines     Chaos Space Marine        4-19           14   
2    Chaos Space Marines      Aspiring Champion           1           14   

  movement weapon_skill ballistic_skill strength toughness wounds attacks  \
0       6"           2+              2+        5         5      8       6   
1       6"           3+              3+        4         4      1       1   
2       6"           3+              3+        4         4      1       2   

  leadership save  
0         10   2+  
1          7   3+  
2          8   3+
```

EDIT: After some tests there was some nested values with `error`, you can omit them and then ouput is:

```
with open('chaos-space-marines.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    

L = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if isinstance(v1, dict):
                L.append({**{'unit': k, 'model': k1}, **v1})

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
                                   unit                               model  \
0                 Abaddon the Despoiler               Abaddon the Despoiler   
1                            Chaos Lord                          Chaos Lord   
2       Chaos Lord in Terminator Armour     Chaos Lord in Terminator Armour   
3                                Cypher                              Cypher   
4                         Daemon Prince                       Daemon Prince   
..                                  ...                                 ...   
122     Hellforged Spartan Assault Tank     Hellforged Spartan Assault Tank   
123  Hellforged Typhon Heavy Siege Tank  Hellforged Typhon Heavy Siege Tank   
124                       Kytan Ravager                       Kytan Ravager   
125                       Chaos Bastion                       Chaos Bastion   
126                     Noctilith Crown                     Noctilith Crown   

    model_count points_value movement weapon_skill ballistic_skill strength  \
0             1         220•       6"           2+              2+        5   
1             1           80       6"           2+              2+        4   
2             1           95       5"           2+              2+        4   
3             1          85•       7"           2+              2+        4   
4             1          150       8"           2+              2+        7   
..          ...          ...      ...          ...             ...      ...   
122           1          320        *            *               *        8   
123           1          720        *            *               *        8   
124           1          430        *           3+              3+        *   
125           1          150        -            -              5+        -   
126           1           85        -            -              4+        -   

    toughness wounds attacks leadership save  
0           5      8       6         10   2+  
1           4      5       4          9   3+  
2           4      6       4          9   2+  
3           4      5       4          9   3+  
4           6      8       4         10   3+  
..        ...    ...     ...        ...  ...  
122         8     20       4          9   2+  
123         9     22       7          9   2+  
124         8     22       *          9   3+  
125        10     20       0          6   4+  
126         8     14       -          -   3+  

[127 rows x 13 columns]
```

EDIT:

You can also check problematic values (why original solution failed) by `else` statements:

```
with open('chaos-space-marines.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

L = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if isinstance(v1, dict):
                L.append({**{'unit': k, 'model': k1}, **v1})
            else:
                print ('inner loop')
                print (v1)
    else:
        print ('outer loop')
        print (v)

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Comment: Hey so this works on the subset data I provided with the question, but it doesnt work with the actual data source and I'm not sure why

https://www.kaggle.com/cjblue83/warhammer-40k-model-stats?select=chaos-space-marines.json

Comment: with both looping or list comprehension methods I get an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping`

Comment: so the previous solution was getting caught on the absence of an inner dictionary in some of the objects? and was reading "error" as a string that it couldnt iterate through?

Comment: @Keagan - Exactly, I can add some proving. Give me a sec.

Comment: @Keagan - Added to answer.